# How do i take fifth power of a number in c

Tags: c++

I am creating a gp calculator in c++ ,But in gp the formulae has common ratio to the power of the term number. in order to get calculate that term i need to know how do i take the number as power for some other number, is there any operator for doing this.

Comment: `auto y = x*x*x*x*x;` ?

Answer (score 1):

If both arguments are floating point numbers, you have to use formula `xᵐ = exp(m log x)`.

Supposedly `std::pow` does that for you. If your program requires to match some particular test patterns, further investigation may be required.

Answer (score 0):

Know your <math>

As long as x != 0 to get any power:

exp(log(x)*power)

The interesting tidbit here is that if power is 1.0/y it will extract the y-root of the value.